# When f is absolutely integrable and contiunous prove that $\sqrt{f}$ is absolutely integrable.

Tags: real-analysis

If $f: (a ,b) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is continuous and absolutely integrable on (a,b), then prove that $\sqrt{f}$ is absolutely integrable on (a,b).

I have that $\sqrt{f}$ is locally integrable. I am working on $|\sqrt{f}|$ is improperly integrable. I think I should do something by comparison, but I am having trouble coming up with what to compare it to.

Comment: Of course $a,b$ are finite.  This fails for $f(x) = 1/x^2$ on $(a,b) = (1,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Sorry, I forgot to put that in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $\sqrt f \le \sup\{f, 1\}$.

Comment: Both f and 1 are absolutely integrable functions so then that implies that $\sqrt{f}$ is?

Comment: Yes, as - for example $\sup\{f,1\} \le 1 + f$, and the absolutely integrable functions form a linear space. Now use comparision.